# Rails - text_field_tag ---- setting a tabindex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

With the Rails text_field_tag --- how do you set an option for the tabindex?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
text_field_tag 'request', nil, :tabindex => '1'
```

Comment: text_field_tag(name, value = nil, html_options = {})